# i was replaced & as &amp; in my url links

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

But again get after w3 validator & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)

following my part of url anchor tag codings

```
<?php

$split_name = explode('and',strtolower($res_cat['cat_name']));

$split_catname = str_replace('','&nbsp;',$split_name[0]);

$category_name = str_replace('and','&amp;',$res_cat['cat_name']);

echo "<li><img src='".$res_cat['cat_icon']."' alt='b_icon'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='catsec.php?act=cat&amp;cat_id=".rtrim($split_catname).''.$res_cat['cat_id']."'>".$category_name."</a></li>";


?>
```

**Example:**

http://mydomainname.com/catsec.php?act=cat&cat_id=energy-41.

I am confused. Help me in advance. Thanks.

Comment: instead of `&` write `&amp;` in your URL, by then the W3C will accept it. please take also a look at http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: i am replaced & as &amp; but i get following type of error in w3 validator,  & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)

…<li><img src='assets/images/b2c/comptr&tel.ico' alt='c_icon1'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;.help me out.i spending 1.5 day for this!!

…p;cat_id= arts, events & occasions-55'> Arts, Events & Occasions</a></li>

Comment: Can you post the html? because when I check this it is oke.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><head>--links--</head><body>---- <div id="item-sec-1">
<ul>
<li><img src='assets/images/b2b/energy.ico' alt='b_icon'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='catsec.php?act=cat&amp;cat_id=energy-41'>Energy &amp; Power</a></li><li><img src='assets/images/b2b/elec.ico' alt='b_icon'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='catsec.php?act=cat&amp;cat_id=electronics-42'>Electronics &amp; Electricals</a></li> </ul>
</div></body></html>   ------>Actualy i above put it particular content onl.chek it .thanks

Answer (score 0):

I check the html you post and below here you find a the replacement that is correct by the W3C

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="item-sec-1">
<ul>
<li><img src='assets/images/b2b/energy.ico' alt='b_icon'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='catsec.php?act=cat&amp;cat_id=energy-41'>Energy &amp; Power</a></li>
<li><img src='assets/images/b2b/elec.ico' alt='b_icon'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='catsec.php?act=cat&amp;cat_id=electronics-42'>Electronics &amp; Electricals</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with your html is that there where -- in the code. And also you missed the title tag that must be there.

if you want to make a comment you should use `<!-- comment here -->`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: where do you check the html code? If I check the code with this validator: http://validator.w3.org/check all seems to be ok.

Comment: m also used same link only.that changes will made it my orignal code inside to checked ..den 1259 chars onl alowing comnt box how am posted my orginal file coding page here....thanks